# logger.info throws result = f(record) # assume callable - will raise if not TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, conda

A basic logger setup can be created using the following python code:

```
import logging

# create and configure main logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# create console handler with a higher log level
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create formatter and add it to the handler
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
secret_filter = False#SecretFilter()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to the logger
handler.addFilter(secret_filter)  # prevent logging of secrets

for hdlr in logger.handlers[:]:  # remove the existing file handlers
     if isinstance(hdlr, logging.FileHandler):
         logger.removeHandler(hdlr)

logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

When saving to the logger using the code snippet:

```
logger.info('setting up logger, done')
```

The output from the console results in :

```
2023-12-18 10:20:45,581 - __main__ - INFO - setting up logger, done
2023-12-18 10:20:45,581 - __main__ - INFO - setting up logger, done
2023-12-18 10:20:45,581 - __main__ - INFO - setting up logger, done
2023-12-18 10:20:45,581 - __main__ - INFO - setting up logger, done
2023-12-18 10:20:45,581 - __main__ - INFO - setting up logger, done
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[27], line 1
    logger.info('setting up logger, done')

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\prod-env-shap\Lib\logging\__init__.py:1489 in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\prod-env-shap\Lib\logging\__init__.py:1634 in _log
    self.handle(record)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\prod-env-shap\Lib\logging\__init__.py:1644 in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\prod-env-shap\Lib\logging\__init__.py:1706 in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\prod-env-shap\Lib\logging\__init__.py:974 in handle
    rv = self.filter(record)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\prod-env-shap\Lib\logging\__init__.py:832 in filter
    result = f(record) # assume callable - will raise if not

TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

I tried many setups and they result in the same issue. Please note im using the following setup:

```
python 3.11.5
pandas 2.1.4
holidays 0.29
scikit-learn 1.3.0
jaydebeapi 1.2.3
boto3 1.29.1
```

Comment: Since my main code was slightly different, I have updated the code to add in a filter to the handle. It seems to create a problem. Therefore its not the boto3 library that was the issue.

Comment: Comment out the following
#secret_filter = False#SecretFilter()
# add the handler to the logger
#handler.addFilter(secret_filter)  # prevent logging of secrets

#for hdlr in logger.handlers[:]:  # remove the existing file handlers
#     if isinstance(hdlr, logging.FileHandler):
#         logger.removeHandler(hdlr)
#logger.addHandler(handler)

Comment: My guess is that `secret_filter = False` is the culprit. Clearly, the `logging` library is trying to call the filter: `f(record) # assume callable - will raise if not`. However, `False` is not callable, so you get the error.